# Tracked Message Events filtered by tracked properties

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have messages in my BizTalk 2013 R2 with promoted properties.

[image: Message Promoted Property]

I want to search in "Tracked Message Events" by this promoted properties, but when I select the Schema Name and want to add a new filter by tracked properties, always is the option "no tracked properties for selected schema".

[image: Tracked Message Events]

I have the message content tracked in this port and is working (I can see the content of the message after search in "Tracked Message Events"), also I have check this OrderNumber property tracked in the Schema.

How can I filter by these properties?

Comment: @felixmodelo did you find the answer for this one? I am struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you enable the tracking of these properties in the property schema properties, like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, those properties are enabled for tracking in my properties schema and also, in the schema itself. I need to restart something? because tracking is working well, but I can't search by those properties.

Comment: Try restarting the (tracking) host instance. Be sure to drop some new files after that, because they should only start showing up from the moment you do the change.

Answer (score 0):

And! Mind that you need to select the Schema Name parameter FIRST! :)